# Get user input from popup

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I am using [rg.plugins.popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup)

I have a routine that checks to see if there is a conflict, and if there is asks the user how they would like to proceed. The routine is a `bool` method that is called at the beginning of a different button press.

If there is no conflict, easy day, no popup required.

I was going to use the `MessingingCenter` to return the user's input, but I am not sure how to make the calling method wait for the response.

I've searched around enough to know that blocking the UI thread is a bad idea.

```
ViewModel
{
  ...
  private void ExecuteFooCommand()
  {
    if (widget.CheckForConclicts)
    {
      //do stuff
    } else 
    {
      //do different stuff
    }
    \\do stuff that is dependent on those results
  }
  ...
}


public class Widget
{
 ...
 public bool CheckForConflicts()
 {
   if (conflicts)
   {
     Messenging.Center.Subscribe<MessagePopup>(this, "DialogResult", (args) =>
     {
       // I'd like to return args.result
     }
   }
  MessagePopup.ShowMessageBox("Alert", msg, true);
  return false;
 }
 ...
}
```

Comment: if the dialog just returns a bool why not use a normal DisplayAlert?

Comment: @Jason, I don't know how to use that via a `ViewModel`. From what I have found, I would still be using the MessengingCenter.